# How to play MP3 from a browser with Java code and JSP?

Tags: java, html, jsp, mp3

What I need is to play MP3 files from a JSP, but I have no idea how.
This is my code for the Java MP3 player, its working fine, the problem is that an I need to play music on my browser (Something like a web service)

```
package reproductor;
import java.io.File;
import javazoom.jlgui.basicplayer.BasicPlayer;

public class Reproductor {
public BasicPlayer player;

public Reproductor() {
    player = new BasicPlayer();
}
public void coge(String y){

}
public void Play() throws Exception {
    player.play();
}

public void AbrirFichero(String ruta) throws Exception {
    player.open(new File(ruta));
    player.play();
}

public void Pausa() throws Exception {
    player.pause();
}

public void Continuar() throws Exception {
    player.resume();
}

public void Stop() throws Exception {
    player.stop();
}
public void reproducemp3 () throws Exception{
   try {
    Reproductor   mi_reproductor = new Reproductor();
        mi_reproductor.AbrirFichero("C:/Users/Welrk/Downloads/preview.mp3");
        mi_reproductor.Play();
    } catch (Exception ex) {
        System.out.println("Error: " + ex.getMessage());
    }
}
public static void main(String args[]) throws Exception{
 Reproductor y = new Reproductor();
 y.AbrirFichero("C:/Users/Welrk/Downloads/preview.mp3");
 y.Play();
}
}
```

I tried something like this, but I'm really lost, any help you can provide would be great

```
<%@page import="java.io.*" %>
<%@ page import="reproductor.*" %>
<%@ page import="reproductor.main"%>
<%@page import="javazoom.jlgui.basicplayer.BasicPlayer" %>
<%@page contentType="text/html" pageEncoding="UTF-8"%>
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>
        <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8">
        <title>JSP Page</title>
    </head>
    <body>
    <%         
        String temp="C:/Users/Welrk/Documents/NetBeansProjects/Musica/web/preview.mp3";        
        Reproductor object = new Reproductor();
        object.player.open(new File(temp));           
    %>
    </body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

Unless your requirements are different (you are forced to use your JSP player), why don't you rely on HTML5 audio control [reference here](http://www.w3.org/wiki/HTML/Elements/audio)?

```
<audio controls>
 <source src="/pathtoyourfile.mp3" type="audio/mpeg">
</audio>
```

Comment: Yes, im forced to use the JSP player, i tried using the methods of my class in the JSP but that didn't work. What i need is the Java code working on my JSP, and i dont know how  S:

Comment: I don't think javazoom.jlgui.basicplayer.BasicPlayer could be run embedded in browser. Only option I see from their websites is to use JavaWS - running as a standalone player in each case.